# Return List of abstract type baseclass object

Tags: c#, oop

```
 public class ChildClassFactory
 {
    public List<BaseClass> Create(int[] numbers)
    {
         // Check: If got 2 items in array create the `Childclass`
       //        If got 3 create the `Child2class`. 
      //        Otherwise exception
      // here i want return all object togather
    }
}
public abstract class BaseClass // base class
{

}
public class Childclass : BaseClass // childclass1st
{

}
public class Child2class : BaseClass // childClass 2nd
{

}
```

In Childclassfactory class method called Create which is return type List<>
How do i return all object together

Comment: Do not tag spam - this in not c++ but C#

Comment: Tagging is not about getting exposure for your question. It's about correctly specifying your problem domain. Don't tag C++ unless you ask about C++.

Comment: Sorry @TalhaIrfan

Comment: I want to create object of both child class depends on argument pass to method

Comment: @GiladGreen Shouldn't it be using the `oop` tag as well?

Comment: @TalhaIrfan - I didn't remove that tag

Comment: @GiladGreen Oh right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Factory design pattern](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/737117/Factory-Pattern-Example-in-Csharp): A naive implementation of it would be:

```
public class ChildClassFactory
{
    public BaseClass Create(int[] numbers)
    {
        if(numbers.Length == 2)
            return new Childclass(numbers[0], numbers[1]);
        if(numbers.Length == 3)
            return new Childclass(numbers[0], numbers[1], number[2]); 
        throw new SomeException();
    }
}
```

More sophisticated implementations will not have an `if else` (or `switch case`) in the `create` method but will have a way to delegate the input to a proper creator class. See more on DoFactory website for: [FactoryMethod](http://www.dofactory.com/net/factory-method-design-pattern) and [Abstract Factory](http://www.dofactory.com/net/abstract-factory-design-pattern) and this blog on [Factory patterns](http://coding-geek.com/design-pattern-factory-patterns/)

Comment: Got it...Thnx bro @Gilad

Comment: @NitinWare Don't forget to upvote this question as well :)

Comment: i am new here . please tell me how to upvote  @TalhaIrfan

Comment: hey @Gilad Green .. can you please tell me how to return all these list of object togather..?????

Comment: @NitinWare On the left hand side of the answer by Gilad, there are two buttons (sandwiched between '1'). Click on upper button to upvote it (score will be incremented from 1 to 2 as proof). I would recommend you to go through the Intro page